# output p value from a t-test in R

Tags: r, p-value

So lets work through the example from `?t.test()`

We do a two-sample t-test on the data by:

```
t.test(1:10, y = c(7:20))
```

Now I am only interested in saving the `p-value`
When I input the followng code, the `$p.value` is also saved.

```
t.test(1:10, y = c(7:20))[3]
```

I want only the `p-value` saved (with the `$p.value`) as an numeric/integer/double. Sorry for asking such a simple question

Comment: Hi @lukeg. You might need to explain yourself more clearly. I don't understand what you're asking. `str(t.test(1:10, y = c(7:20))[3])` says that the value you're getting is already numeric. You can save that value to another variable with something like `pVal <- t.test(1:10, y = c(7:20))$p.value`.

Comment: I am running a loop and getting an error `Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'´ but by using the $p.value command, the error is elimainated. So thanks!

Comment: Good to hear! I'll post my comment as a proper answer in keeping with the Way Things Are Done.

Comment: Don't apologize. R has truly terrible documentation of object attributes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can save the p-value from the t-test to another variable with something like:

`pVal <- t.test(1:10, y = c(7:20))$p.value`

`pVal` will then be numeric:

```
> str(pVal)
num 1.86e-05
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test <- t.test(df$column1, df$column2, paired = TRUE)

test$p.value
```